# Is there any relationships between path cover number and chromatic number?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let G be a finite simple graph. Consider the independent number $\alpha$, the chromatic number $\chi$ and the path cover number (also called the path partition number) $\rho$.
Then we have $\alpha\chi \ge n$ and $\alpha \ge \rho$.

Is there any relationships between the path cover number $\rho$ and the chromatic number $\chi$ ? For example, is the inequality $\rho\chi\ge n$ true?

Comment: For a simple path $P_3$ on three vertices we have: $n=3$, $\rho=1$, $\chi=2$.

Comment: Yes, the path has low chromatic number and path cover number.

Comment: There is also this almost obvious inequality $\chi+\rho\leq n+1$

Comment: @kabenyuk You have any insight as to why the inequality $\chi+\rho\le n+1$ is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vidyarthi: The answer to your question is too long for a comment.

Let $G$ be a simple graph and let $\rho$ be the smallest integer such that there exists a system of pairwise disjoint paths $P_1,\ldots,P_\rho$ containing all vertices of $G$. Then we assume $\rho(G)=\rho$. By the way, sometimes $\rho(G)=-1$ is assumed if $G$ is hamiltonian and $\rho(G)=0$ if $G$ is hamiltonian but not hamiltonian-connected.

It is argued that the following statement is true.

> For any graph $G$ the following inequality holds:
> $$ \chi(G)+\rho(G)\leq n+1, 
> $$ where
> $n$ is the order of graph $G$ and $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of
> $G$.

*Proof.*
Choose in each path $P_i$ one of its ends. Denote this vertex by $v_i$.
The set $X=\{v_1,\ldots,v_\rho\}$ is an independent set in the graph $G$. In fact, if $v_iv_j$ is an edge of $G$, then we can replace paths $P_i$ and $P_j$ by one path $P=P_i\cup P_j$. Contradiction.

Now let us color all vertices of $X$ with the same color.

Let us paint the remaining $n-\rho$ vertices of graph $G$ in $n-\rho$ other different colors.
Thus we used exactly $n-\rho+1$ colors for the correct coloring of graph $G$. Hence $\chi\leq n-\rho+1$.